# Global sender/contact photo across webmail and email clients

Tags: email, dovecot, postfix-mta

PayPal, Amazon, and other large companies set a contact/sender photo in their automatic emails. This looks very professional, however, documentation on how to do this seems to be very limited. To elaborate, by default, most email services have a default contact photo or use say, the first letter of the sender name and have it be the contact photo. I want to use my own.

Is there any single way to cover most services, via an HTML tag or something else? Using a self-hosted Postfix-Dovecot combination.

Answer (score 0):

Most email services like `gmail` use `Gravatar` image for the Avatar shown. Create an account for the email you want and put desired picture.

Comment: I don't think so? Set it up and it doesn't work, for Gmail at least.